# THREE.TrackballControls rotation center

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have 1 object on scene and want to rotate it relative to its axis. I use THREE.TrackballControls. But when my object in not in the center of screen, rotation is bad (it is rotating relative to center of screen). I tried to change camera position before creating controls. But it did not work.

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 3;
    camera.position.y = 10;

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
```

Is it possible to specify the center of camera rotation in TrackballControls? (So object will rotate not relatively center of scene)

Thanks,
Zhenya

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TrackballControls` is rotating the *camera*, not the object.

You can set the `controls.target` like so:

```
controls.target.set( x, y, z );
```

three.js r.58

Comment: ah, set the cam initial position but not cam lookAt before `new THREE.TrackballControls`, then after use `.target.set` for the desired initial cam lookAt point.

Comment: I am using this code var bb = new THREE.Vector3(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.center());                  controls.target.set(bb.x, bb.y, -6000); But it is not working..